# Regex to allow only positive whole numbers and checking validity in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I have two input field like this in my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="txtminFeedback" pattern="^\d+([\.\,][0]{2})?$" placeholder="Minimum Feedback">

<input type="text" class="txtmaxFeedback" pattern="^\d+([\.\,][0]{2})?$" placeholder="Maximum Feedback">
```

I've tried several regex patterns like following:

```
^\d+([\.\,][0]{2})?$

or

(^[0-9]+$|^$)

or

/^\d*$/
```

None of these worked whatsoever with the following code in jQuery:

```
if ($('.txtminFeedback').val() == "" && $('.txtmaxFeedback').val() == "") {
    if ($('.txtmin')[0].checkValidity() && $('.txtmax')[0].checkValidity()) {
        if ($('.txtSearch').val() == "") {
            ShowMessage("Please enter the search term!");
            return;
        }
        else {
            PostAndUpdate($('.txtSearch').val(), $('input[name=type]:checked').val(), $('input[name=shipping]:checked').val(), $('input[name=condition]:checked').val(), $('.txtmin').val(), $('.txtmax').val(), $('.txtNegativeKeywords').val(), $('.txtminFeedback').val(), $('.txtmaxFeedback').val());
        }
    } else {
        ShowMessage("You have entered incorrect value for minimum or maximum price!");
        return;
    }
} else if (!$('.txtminFeedback')[0].checkValidity() || !$('.txtmaxFeedback')[0].checkValidity())
{
    ShowMessage("Please enter only positive value for minimum and maximum feedback.");
    return;
}
```

User can leave the txtminfeedback and txtmaxfeedback empty if he wants. However if he decides to enter some values, then both fields must be entered and will require to have entered only whole positive numbers (from 0 to 4 million).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0">` ?

Comment: @AlexK. sry I forgot to mention that nothing happens even if I enter whole positive numbers in the field with these 3 regex patterns. For example when I enter 1 and 5000 , nothing happens, but it should...

Comment: Maybe you need to clean the regex a bit: `pattern="\d+([.,]0{2})?"` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still the same,  I can enter aaa and qqq in fields but validation still isn't triggered

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm getting an error in console that regex pattern isnt valid

Comment: No idea what you mean, `/^\d+([.,]0{2})?$/u.test("11.00")` prints true.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I ment like whole numbers without point .00, just 100 , 50, not 100.00 or 50.00 :)

Comment: Then why do you allow whitespace only input? `pattern="\d+"` will do. This is not good to post an unclear answer, keep the requirements to yourself, and then post an answer. I'd rather delete the post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to make the field optional. For example if both fields are empty, search can go through. If one of the two fields isn't empty and has a valid value (positive number) then other field must be required, since they go in pair... That's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: (Sorry, I mean an unclear *question* in the post above). It is great you found an answer that works for you, just if you want to keep it online, it would be a good idea to update the question with the actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this did it:

```
 pattern="^(\s*|\d+)$"


 if ($('.txtminFeedback')[0].checkValidity()==false || $('.txtmaxFeedback')[0].checkValidity()==false) {
                ShowMessage("Please enter only positive value for minimum and maximum feedback.");
                return;
            }
            if ($('.txtmin')[0].checkValidity() && $('.txtmax')[0].checkValidity()) {
                if ($('.txtSearch').val() == "") {
                    ShowMessage("Please enter the search term!");
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    PostAndUpdate($('.txtSearch').val(), $('input[name=type]:checked').val(), $('input[name=shipping]:checked').val(), $('input[name=condition]:checked').val(), $('.txtmin').val(), $('.txtmax').val(), $('.txtNegativeKeywords').val(), $('.txtminFeedback').val(), $('.txtmaxFeedback').val());
                }
            } else {
                ShowMessage("You have entered incorrect value for minimum or maximum price!");
                return;
            }
```

Just in case someone in future might need it.

Cheers =)